# How to protect data transmitted by socket?

Tags: python, sockets, security, ssl

This code is for sending and receiving between my PC and AWS Instance
I want to know whether the transmitted data is considered secure? or do I need something else to ensure the security of the transmitted data?
If the data is not encrypted, what is the addition to the code to make it secure?

code's client

```py
import socket

HOST = "public ip of server"

PORT = 4444  # The port used by the server


with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:

    s.connect((HOST, PORT))

    s.sendall(b"Hello, world")

    data = s.recv(1024)



print(f"Received {data!r}")
```

server's code

server code

```py
import socket



HOST = "0.0.0.0" 

PORT = 4444  #open this in your router 



with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:

    s.bind((HOST, PORT))

    s.listen()

    conn, addr = s.accept()

    with conn:

        print(f"Connected by {addr}")

        while True:

            data = conn.recv(1024)

            if not data:

                break

            conn.sendall(data)
```

Comment: Everything is in the documentation : https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html

Comment: No, it's not secure, all that traffic is sent unprotected.

Comment: I read about the topic, but I don't know how to implement the SSL code and how to encapsulate the data sent and received between the two parties